# Server server static content which is generated dynamically

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a web app which gets photos via uploading and saves them in a folder called Pictures(which is in /home/andrei/Pictures) and then i want to display them through servlets(within html documents).
I heard i had to use a front servlet and that i will have a domain but i did not manage to do it. Could you show me how to do it?

(I saw some ways but i did not get it)

Other information:
OS: Linux Ubuntu
Server: Apache Tomcat v7
IDE: Eclipse

Comment: i just wanted to emphasize that i can`t just include them in the WebContent and republish

Comment: ...and it is NOT `front server`, i would call it rather a `front servlet` (which will be used to expose the image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a complete example of how you can use Servlets to expose an image to your client http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html

The modification you have to do is here:

```
String filename = sc.getRealPath("image.gif");
```

You just have to include the fullpath yo your image...

Good Luck!

**UPDATE**

You can display the image in html using:

```
<img src="/ServletName?id=xxxx" ... ... ... />
```

This, will cause the browser to make an http request to your servlet with `< url-pattern >` = `ServletName` and fetch the image with `id=xxxx` to the client browser

Comment: well i want to give the image within an html page

Comment: aaaaa yes, now i get it. How could i not have thought about it...
Thanks so much dude! :D